# Automatic jenkins master discovery and monitoring using nagios

Tags: jenkins, nagios

I want a way to automatically discover Jenkins master servers and automatically monitor the health of the jobs on those Jenkins master servers so that I can look at a single console(using nagios host) to detect issues when a job is failing anywhere in integration.

Could someone help me out to finding Jenkins master servers using nagios?

Comment: I don't know whether Nagios supports it, but you can auto-discover Jenkins instances via multicast DNS or UDP: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Auto-discovering+Jenkins+on+the+network

Comment: auto-discover Jenkins instances via multicast DNS or UDP using ***C#*** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a nagios plugin for retrieving job health information from Jenkins, but it looks like it requires manual configuration for each job, see [Nagios Jenkins plugin](https://github.com/jonlives/nagios-jenkins-plugin).

I'm not familiar enough with nagios to know how any built-in auto-discovery works, but it looks like there are several example scripts ([check_find_new_hosts](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-and-Systems-Management/Nagios/check_find_new_hosts/details) and [device discovery](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Tutorials/Other-Tutorials-And-HOWTOs/Device-Auto-2DDiscovery-and-Printer-Monitoring-Configuration-for-Nagios/details)) for generating the necessary configuration from a network scan. You'll have to do some work to integrate the results of the scan into your nagios instance. (IIRC, you need to restart nagios after writing new configuration?)

To get the list of Jenkins servers, you can build on one of the existing network scan scripts for nagios. The script should scan an IP range and identify devices that respond to `http://IP:8080/api/xml`. The resulting XML document (JSON results are also supported) should contain a root tag named `<hudson>` (in my instance, maybe this will change to "jenkins" in a future release). If the server responds to this request, then you'll want your script to generate the nagios configuration for monitoring it.

In addition, the XML response will contain a list of jobs, like:

```
<job>
  <name>My Job</name>
  <url>http://jenkins:8080/job/My%20job/</url>
  <color>blue</color>
</job>
```

By iterating through this list, you get the job names, job urls (for more details or polling for status), and the current statuses (blue means success). This list of jobs can provide input to the Nagios Jenkins plugin configuration.

The [Jenkins Remote API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) is documented on your Jenkins instance, just go to `http://jenkins:8080/api`.

Comment: Thank You Dave for making me understand on jenkins REST API,
Now I can check jenkins is running on remote server or not.
I am using check_http plugin for remote host on which check_mk_agent is installed.
Ex. ./check_http -H host_name -u /api/xml?depth=0 -p 8080

Yes we need to restart nagios after writting new configuration.
I use this command to reload/restart the nagios 'check_mk -R'
Once again thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Dave,
Could you please through some light on following topic
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036749/monitor-jenkins-jobs-health-using-nagios-gui
Thanks