# Monitor jenkins jobs health using nagios GUI

Tags: jenkins, hudson, monitoring, nagios

I am using `check_http` plugin for discovering jenkins service(Winstone hosted and Apache hosted) is running or not on hosts on which `check_mk_agent` is installed. And its been monitored on single ui that is nagios GUI, using following command.

```
./check_http -H Host_Name -u /api/xml?depth=0 -p 8080
```

Next step is to parse the jobs on specific jenkins master server using `jenkins REST api` and  monitor each job's health in `nagios GUI`.

Could someone please give me any idea on this so that I can monitor the jenkins jobs on single GUI. Any script or plugin much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use XML::Twig;
use HTTP::Request;
use Getopt::Long;
use Nagios::Plugin;
#use File::stat;

use File::Basename;
my $PROGNAME = basename($0);

my $p = Nagios::Plugin->new(
    usage => "Usage: %s [ -H|--host ] [ -p|--port ]",
    extra => "
    Examples:
    $PROGNAME --host myhost -port 8080
    Check Host name and port.
");

$p->add_arg(
    spec => 'host|f=s',
    required => 1,
    help => "-H, --host=Hostname. REQUIRED.");

$p->add_arg(
    spec => 'port|a=i',
    default => 8080,
    help => "-p, --port=Portnumber. Default 8080.");

$p->getopts;

my $o_host = $p->opts->host ;
my $o_port = $p->opts->port;
my $protocol = 'http';
my $o_url = '/api/xml';
my @jobs;

my $url = $protocol . "://" . $o_host . ":" . $o_port . $o_url ;
#print $url,"\n";
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(10);
$ua->env_proxy;
my $response = $ua->get($url);
if ($response->is_success) {
    my $content = $response->decoded_content;  # or whatever
    XML::Twig->new( twig_roots => { 'job/name' => sub { push @jobs, $_->text; } }) ->parseurl( $url);
}
else {
    $p->nagios_die( CRITICAL, "Bad page found" );
}
#print @jobs;
foreach my $job_name (@jobs) {
        #print $job_name;
        my $job_url = $protocol . "://" . $o_host . ":" . $o_port . "/" . "job" . "/" . $job_name . $o_url ;
        #print $job_url;
        my $response2 = $ua->get($job_url);
        #print $job_url;
        if ($response2->is_success) {
            $p->nagios_die( OK, "Job link valid" );
        }
        else {
            $p->nagios_die( CRITICAL, "Bad page found" );
        }
}
```