# What is the best practice for a jenkins hearbeat script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have multiple Jenkins instances running that do not necessarily have a slave/master relationship. What is the best way to have them monitor each other and warn an admin if one instance goes down. The current approach I am using is to have a job on instance A that triggers a job on instance B, which then in turn checks that the resources of instance B are healthy. Instance B then performs the same trigger process on instance A. Is this a good setup? what is the best way to trigger a job and get the output status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a good setup?

If it works for your use case, it is a good setup; that is, you don't find yourself tweaking the scripts frequently, or being falsely alarmed.

There may be cases where using the job queue is problematic - e.g. there are many jobs to execute before that one, or some long-running ones that block the heartbeat to be processed. Then, perhaps it is possible to keep one job executor free to perform jobs like the heartbeat; 
[this one (Job Restrictions)](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+Restrictions+Plugin) seems to fit.

Additionally, coupling the heartbeats sequentially means after the first failure, there is no more information about all other nodes in the sequence; so when instance A is down, you don't know the state of instance B.

---

I'd check server monitoring software: [nagios](https://www.nagios.org/), [cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) etc. You'll find scripts that integrate Jenkins into it, and it looks like integrating monitoring jobs is fairly easy; [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036749/monitor-jenkins-jobs-health-using-nagios-gui), meMangesh wrote a script that checks whether a particular jenkins job URL can be accessed via HTTP.

Using such software has the additional benefit that you get hints at what to look for on servers - e.g. when hard disk partitions run full, when the server's load is running high, etc.